# Displaying information using nested repeaters and charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is the html i have right now, and it does display what i want:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeatAwareOfStat">
          <ItemTemplate>
                <h1><%#((VitaminWDefaultClient.Entities.StatsPosition)Container.DataItem).PositionName%></h1>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("KnownFrom") %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name") %>: <%# Eval("Count") %><br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

However, i would like to use a chartplugin, and that causes some problems.

This should be the table as i want it after the information is filled:

```
<table class="highchart" data-graph-container-before="1" data-graph-type="column">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Occupation</th>
                                <th>some other place</th>
                                <th>Facebook</th>
                                <th>twitter</th>
                                <th>magazine</th>
                                <th>whatevr</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Daglig leder</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Some title</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                            </tr>                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Some title</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                            </tr>                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Some title</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>10</td>
                            </tr>                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Some title</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                            </tr>                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Restaurantworker</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Here is a picture of the objects im working with

[image]

Codebehind:

```
    var list = JobBLL.LoadAwareOfStatistics();
    repeatAwareOfStat.DataSource = list;
    repeatAwareOfStat.DataBind();
```

Adding the table inside the repeaters was rather difficult. Anyone able to help?

Comment: You could copy the tbl, and paste it into a formview template. Or do you use codebehind?

Comment: var list = JobBLL.LoadAwareOfStatistics();
            repeatAwareOfStat.DataSource = list;
            repeatAwareOfStat.DataBind();

This is the only thing im using codebehind